# How to Restrict file upload to wrong file extensions in rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am using rails 4.0 + ruby 2.0 + carrierwave + rmagic gems

i am having a problem in uploading files.. i want to allow users to upload files which the system allows...

for example.. I allow files to be uploaded by users having extension of *.jpg. So, in the file selection window they must see only files with the jpg extension.

**view**

```
<%= wrap_input_field("#{f.file_field  :image,  :accept => "image/jpg", :multiple => true}", "<b>Files Upload:</b><span class= 'text-danger'> </span>") %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding:

```
def extension_white_list
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
end
```

to your uploader model.